# Heuristic to find a primary key in a text file

Tags: database, csv, primary-key

I am looking for a library to find a primary key from text file. Imagine that i have a CSV file and i dont know which column(s) is the primary key. Is there any library that helps me to do that (using some kind of heuristic)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that not knowing which, if any, field in a file is a primary key is not a programming problem but a **business** problem. This something I would send back to the business to get an answer.  Reasons are below.

First what is expected to be a primary key and isn't in a particular version of a file often shows a problem with the file and it should not be processed. For example in my job, I often need to process sales rosters which could come as CSVs. In them any sales sales territory should be unique. This is a business rule. Occasionally we get rosters where they are not unique and we fail the import because two poeple cannot be assigned to the same territory at the same time. Usually it is problem where one person left and another took his place, but we have no way of knowing which of the two records is the correct one. Hence the import fails. But checking a file that contained this type of information programmically would have failed to find this as a PK becasue it wasn't unique inteh file when it should have been.

Next the checking existance of unique data in a column when a file is first processed does not guarantee that data will remain unique over time or that it is meaningful as a PK.

For instance, zip code might be unique today, but three weeks from now it might not be as someone new is added to the mix.

Nor is zip code likely to be a candidate PK unless the file is only about zip codes.

Part number is another case where it might appear to be unique but not be on a CSV file because parts from differnt manufacturers can have the same part number, so the uniqueness comes from the combination of partnumber and manufacturer.  But again that is a business rule becausee some manufacturers might use the same part number for different versions of the same thing like the ones of differnt colors and others might have a buisiness rule they be unique. Without knowing the data meaning to the particular people providing the files and using the data, you have no idea whther it should be a PK or not.

Determination of a PK is about more than uniqueness of data, it is about the meaning of the the data. Yes you can identify possible PKs (and then like in the first case described above, you might be wrong using an automated tool) to check but you should not  choose one automatically without addressing the meaning of the data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a library to do this, but you could definitely use Python's built in CSV parser and find out which column has unique values and that column is definitely at least a candidate key.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Import the CSV file into MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Then try and create  a unique index on each column.   Or  run this query

```
select  count(*) `ID count`,  (select count(*) from csv_table ) total from 
(select distinct csv_col_1   from csv_table )  distinct_rows;
```

on each column.  If the ID count equals the  total number of rows, it's a primary key candidate.

Comment: If I need to check Col1+Col2+Col3 combination? How to check all possible combinations of columns?